# Need help on Registering App on PCF with Spring Cloud Data Flow which is also on PCF

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, pcfdev

1) I have registered a sink app on PCF using cf push -p abcdef.jar sinkapp. it went good

2) Now I have my SCDF server also on PCF

How can I register sinkapp on the SCDF server using dataflow which is on the same PCF , same org, same space. coz I have no clue what do I reference this to for registering it ? I am looking for the command that I can give to the SCDF from dataflow shell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend going through the [getting-started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started) experience for Cloud Foundry.

You should *not* be pushing the apps standalone and manually; instead, you'd ["register"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps) the app(s) in SCDF, and you'd then use the registered app(s) in the stream definition.

When you deploy the stream, SCDF will interpret the definition and in turn, it will push the apps to the desired org/space on your behalf. Here's a [sample manifest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_sample_manifest_template) for SCDF, where you'd define the org/space and other overrides.

Comment: Let's say I have my app on my local with Group and Artifact Id as "com.example" and "sinkapp" respectively...so basically run the PCF SCDF server jar and then register the "sinkapp" which is on my local using " dataflow:>app register -uri maven://com.example:sinkapp:0.0.1-snapshot.jar" command ?

Comment: Your local-maven is locally in your computer. When you run SCDF in CF (it's a remote environment), whatever is in your local-repo won't be visible to the app running in CF.

If you have to consume apps in CF, those apps need to be also remotely reachable, and that is typically consumed from organization's artifactory. You can configure the remote repositories when pushing SCDF to CF.

Comment: Here are [few other alternatives](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-app-resolution-options) how you can resolve apps in CF. Please consider closing this thread and opening a new one for other questions.

Comment: @Sabby...I am sorry I did not mention that I am running on PCF Dev...its on my local VM. Now, how do I reference my Maven Repositories from this ?

Comment: My custom Processors are on my local and I need to register them in the PCF Dev VM  I got on my machine. Any help is grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Also I am using Kafka brokers which are again on my local and I wanna use them for my streams on PCF Dev. How can I do this since there are no Kafka services that are available on PCF DEv

Comment: It is the same requirement for PCFDev, too. The containers are running inside a VM and they won't have access to local-maven-repo. You can, however, run the CF-server locally (via `java -jar ...`) instead of pushing it to PCFDev. But make sure to set PCFFev env-var's for the server before you start it. That way, the server will run locally on your laptop and it will have access to local-maven-repo, but the actual apps will be deployed to PCFDev by SCDF.

Comment: As for Kafka, you can _only_ make it work if it is remotely reachable. Once you have externally accessible hosts/IPs for Kafka, you can supply that as CUPs in PCFDev. I'd suggest that you use the Rabbit that ships with PCFDev instead of making Kafka work - you are in development anyway.

Comment: "You can, however, run the CF-server locally (via java -jar ...) instead of pushing it to PCFDev. But make sure to set PCFFev env-var's for the server before you start it. "--Didnt quite get this Sabby. You want me to run "Local SCDF Jar or CF Jar from my terminal"...Confused...

Comment: I was referring to this [option in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-cloudfoundry-on-local).